# Google Maps API and JavaScript Issues :-(

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

Ive been working on a Google Maps application and have hit a hurdle due to a lack of knowledge in js  me thinks?!

So... here's my JSON object

```
{"pickuppoint0":"LE9 8GB","pickuppoint1":"LE2 0QA","pickuppoint2":"LE3 6AF","pickuppoint3":"LE2 8GB","pickuppoint4":"LE8 8TE","pickuppoint5":"LE2 2GB","pickuppoint6":"LE1 6AF"}
```

And here's a loop through the JSON object...

```
     $.each(alltravelgroups, function(k, v){ 
        for(var i=0; i < boxes.length; i++){
          var bounds = boxes[i];
          if(bounds.contains(getLatLng(v))){
            alert("im here");
          }
        }
      });
```

And here's my getLatLng() method I've created...

```
function getLatLng(pickuppoint) {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': pickuppoint}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
     return results[0].geometry.location
    } else {
      alert('getLatLng Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Now... what I'm trying to do is simply take the value from each key/value pair and produce a LatLng object that can then be used within the "bounds.contains()" method for searching within the bounds box provided by the RouteBoxer class.

The problem I'm facing is the value returned by the getLatLng method is "undefined" when using alert(getLatLng(v)) and should just be a 'location' containing both latitude and longitde? Anyone able to point what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The geocoder is asynchronous, you can't return data from the callback routine, you need to _use_ it there.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the link below.

http://jsfiddle.net/y829C/13/

```
  var mapOptions = {
                 center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316),
                  zoom: 8,
                 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

             };
```

In the above code, semicolon is missing in return results[0].geometry.location.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that wasn't the issue... I was trying to return a geocode directly from a function when I actually needed to create a callback method. Good spot on the ; by the way too ;-O